# Advection-style first order nonlinear PDE system

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, functional-equations, statistical-mechanics, integro-differential-equations

Given functions $a(t,x,y) > 0, d(t,x) >0$ and constants $b,c > 0$, I would like to find the three functions $u(t,x),v(t,x) , w(t,x,y)$ that solve the system:

\begin{align}
u_t - u_x &= -\left(\int_0^x a(t,x,y)\mathrm{d}y+b\right) u(t,x) + c v(t,x) + w_y(t,x,0) + d(t,x)\\ 
v_t - v_x &= b u(t,x) - c v(t,x) + b \int_0^x w(t,x,y) \mathrm{d} y\\
w_t - w_x - w_y &= a(t,x,y) u(t,x)  - b w(t,x,y),
\end{align}

and satisfy $u(t,0)=v(t,0)=w(t,x,0) = 0$.

### Interpretation : the state of a job allocating platform

- $u,w,v$ - is the number of workers $u$noccupied, $w$orking or on a sick lea$v$e.
- $x$ - is the remaining duration of the working contract, by the end of which a worker leaves the system
- $y$ - is the remaining duration of a job assignment
- $a(t,x,y)$ - is the probability of being assigned a job of duration $y$ at date $t$
- $d(t,x)$ - is the number of new workers joining the platform at date $t$ for the duration $x$
- $b,c$ - is the chance of falling ill and that of recovering.

Once a job assignment is over ($y=0$), the busy worker joins the ranks of the unoccupied (the $w_y(t,x,0)$ term in the $u$-equation). Once the contract is over ($x=0$) the worker leaves the platform.

I kind of found the solution to a linear 1st order PDE system in the Andrei D. Polyanin's [bestiary](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/), but am absolutely at loss about what to do with the $w_y(t,x,0)$ and $\int w \mathrm{d}y $ terms.

Although not exactly a model of a physics phenomenon, this system looks like something that the physicists are most likely to be familiar with.
I would be immensely grateful for the solution and/or all the pointers to the sources treating this kind of problems (lectures, keywords, etc.).

### Update

Noticing that for every worker *the date of retirement*, $T_x$,  and for every job *the date of expiry*, $T_y$, are constants, I can use the substitution $x = T_x - t$ and $y = T_y - t$ to transform equations 2 and 3 into ODEs, solve them and reverse the substitution to obtain $w,v$ in terms of $u$:

\begin{align*}
w(t,x,y) & = \int_0^t \int_{s}^{y+s} \mathrm{e}^{-b s} a_y(t-s,x+s,\xi) u(t-s,x+s) \mathrm{d}\xi \mathrm{d} s \\
v(t,x) & = b \int_0^t \int_{s}^{x + s} \mathrm{e}^{-cs} u_x(t-s,\xi) + W_x(t-s,\xi) \mathrm{d} \xi \mathrm{d} s.
\end{align*}

where

\begin{equation*}
    W(t,x) := \int_0^x w(t,x,y) \mathrm{d} y,
\end{equation*}

is the total size of the busy group across all job durations.

Plugging these expressions into the first equation one gets the following PDE in $u$:

\begin{align}
u_t =& u_x - \left(\int_0^x a\mathrm{d}y +b \right) u \\
     & + cb \int_0^t \int_{s}^{x + s} \mathrm{e}^{-cs} u_x(t-s,\xi)\mathrm{d} \xi \mathrm{d} s \\ 
     & + cb \int_0^t \int_{s}^{x + s} \mathrm{e}^{-cs} W_x(t-s,\xi) \mathrm{d} \xi \mathrm{d} s \\
     & + \int_0^t \mathrm{e}^{-bs} a_y(t-s,x+s,0) u(t-s, x+s) \mathrm{d}\xi \\
     & + d(t,x).
\end{align}

Comment: The question as asked belongs on the maths site. Cross-posting in this way is not appropriate -- the question needs to be explicitly edited to address each site you post it on, and saying "this is a mathematical problem that physicists might be familiar with" (note: physicists, not physicians) is not sufficient tailoring nor sufficient grounds to be on-topic here. (Questions need to be *about* physics, not just have a tangential connection.) Moreover, if you do cross-post, you need to clearly label this on every copy.

Comment: My apologies, Emilio, I am sorry to have broken the rules, but it turns out the math site is a swamp, whereas here I got a useful comment 10 min after posting. 
Could you please point me to the instructions on how to cross post properly without recasting the model as one of a physics phenomenon? I am not fluent in physics since highschool, I'm an economist.

The "physicians" joke is very funny :)

Comment: @ Konstantin I'm sure the "physicians" joke is funny the first couple of times, but it's worth considering your audience before using it.

Comment: The general cross-posting guidelines are [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068). If you're looking for the guidelines regarding how to post here a question that is not about physics without putting in any work to make it about physics, then, as you should be able to guess, there aren't any. If MSE doesn't provide answers, then the standard methods of bringing attention to a question apply. Regarding the answer you got here, there's nothing physics- nor physicist-specific about it. This thread belongs on MSE.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty the value of physics is that it is applicable well beyond studying "physical phenomena". Physicists are in great demand due to the ability of creating models for a wide range of phenomena. The question clearly belongs to the domain of "mathematical physics".

Comment: @Vadim As e.g. Wikipedia describes it, mathematical physics refers to "the development of mathematical methods for application to problems in physics". This question does nothing of the sort. There's nothing wrong with this question, but it is simply not about physics. The question of whether this site should be open to questions that are not about physics, (being instead about math that could benefit from the eyes of a physicist) has been litigated multiple times on Meta. If you or Konstantin feel it should be revisited, then it should be -- on Meta.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty while wikipedia is a useful source, it is not an authority, as the articles are often written by people with limited knowledge. Specifically, in the FSU countries "mathematical physics" refers to methods of solving PDEs - books and university courses are named this way. Same can be said about non-linear theory (aka "theory of oscillations"). Finally, your answer does not address my main argument about broader applicability of our methods.

Comment: @Vadim You're welcome to litigate the scope of mathematical physics as it is understood on this site, and the topicality of questions on the "broader applicability" of physics methods to non-physics questions, on Meta. As of this writing the consensus is very clear (and documented e.g. [here](//physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5713), [here](//physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7140) and [here](//physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/164)). If you think it should change, by all means argue for it -- **in Meta** where the debate will be visible.

Comment: @Emilio I went through every question in the cited Meta posts, and I find it unfair to put my post in the same basket. I honestly started from an actual problem, formalized it and brought it to the people who solve problems about the real world. Think of Feynman's rotating plate. Or that "share of visible surface" question, you so gloriously answered. How is that one about pure physics? It reeks of (analytical) geometry

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a nice example of a system of equations solvable by the Laplace transform (I suppose that we are interested only in $x,y>0$ here):
$$
\bar{u}(p,t)=\int_0^{+\infty}dx u(x,t)e^{-px}, etc.
$$
This should reduce it to a system of linear ordinary differential equations in respect to time, which can be solved. Then one uses the Laplace transform table to try to obtain the solution in $(x,t)$ variables.

**Update**.
Another rather general approach that works particularly well for the first order PDEs is the method if characteristics (see the section "Two-dimensional theory" [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_partial_differential_equation#:%7E:text=Such%20equations%20arise%20in%20the,involves%20the%20method%20of%20characteristics.)).

Comment: Thanks for your interest? I could totally do that if I had a single locational variable, but what should I do with the $w(t,x,y)$ equation?

Comment: You transform it in respect to both $x$ and $y$. Obviously, you have two different laplace variables (e.g., $p$ for $x$, and $s$ for $y$)

Comment: So, I have two complex arguments in the transformed system? Ok, I had a hunch but didn't dare to proceed

Comment: It may make things more clear, if you denote these variables as $p_x, p_y$ - then it looks analogous, e.g., to solving a wave equation is several dimensions.

Comment: I don't know what to do with the LTs of $w_y(t,x,0)$ and $\int_0^x w(t,x,y) d y$. $a(y)$ also looks innocent only in this special case, if I allow it to depend on $t,x$ I get convolutions in LT equations.

Comment: @Konstantin if you post more details about how you approach it, I will try to help. Note also the additional suggestion that I added to my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116975/discussion-between-konstantin-and-vadim).